How do I get Vite to work with Laravel (Blade) for Styles and Scripts?
I'm working with Laravel 11 (with blade). 11 Comes with Vite and I'm trying to use it..
Here is my config file vite.config.json (in my root directory):
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});

This is how it was installed with the new L11 project...
In my /resources directory, I have this:

My app.js file is importing each of those other files:
import "./axios";
import "./cancel";
import "./dropdown";
import "./patient";

I'll be honest, I'm not great with JS, so I'm guessing it's in my .js files that I'm messing this up -- here's my cancel.js:
function cancel() {
    history.back();
}

Obviously, super simple while I try and get this to work..
I tried doing export function cancel() {...} but that didn't work either.
In my main blade layout, I have this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ $title ?? config('app.name') }}</title>

    {{-- Scripts --}}
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    @vite(['resources/js/app.js']) // THIS PART DOES NOT APPEAR TO WORK

    {{-- Font Awesome 4.7.0 --}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    {{-- Styles --}}
    @vite(['resources/sass/styles.scss']) // THIS PART WORKS

    {{-- Favicons --}}
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>

<body>
    <x-navigation-bar />
    {{ $slot }}
</body>

</html>

In one of my blade files, I have an onclick for a button cancel that should trigger the above cancel.js file's function, but it says the function is undefined.
I have run npm run build and npm run dev with no change.
I tried reading up on this in Laravel's documentation, but I can't seem to get it to work.
Any suggestions?

Try :
window.cancel = () => {     history.back(); }, i think the problem might be related to the renaming that vite does

Not sure it'll make a difference, but you typically don't put .js in the <head> section, but rather at the end of <body>. I was able to get your code to work with window.cancel = () => { ... }; (assigning the cancel function to the window global JS object), same as Mohammad above.

So you're saying I should export them as es6 arrow functions? Am I understanding you right (since I have other functions that work differently.. or don't work in this case)? @Mohammadsiabbou

and that was by putting the @vite for my .js after my body?

Yes, but again, that doesn't seem to make a difference, just convention. You can use es6 or other syntax, like window.cancel = function() { ... }, but the most important part is that window., which yours is missing.

Interesting - I really need to study up more on js, Let me play with it and see if the other functions work ok.

Yeah, omitting window. makes it a "local" function, i.e. usable inside of that .js file, but not others. If you do const cancel = () => { alert('test'); }, then add cancel(); immediately below that, you should see that alert pop up, but if you then try to open your console (F12 in any browser), and type cancel(), you get the undefined reference error. I think this has something to do with how vite imports the .js files as modules, but my JS knowledge is only so deep

Looks like it's working - do you want to throw in an answer and I'll mark it? Now I just need to figure out how to pass route urls, but that's a different topic for a different day :)

The thing is not related to es6 arrow functions, it's related to the scope, vite changes the file content and renames the function and variable, so technically there is no such thing as "cancel" in the file. But when you attach it to the window that makes it global and vite won't change its name so you can access it outside the file. Hope you understand.

Also note "onclick" attributes were outdated 20 years ago. You should just define proper event listeners in your script file then you don't have to worry about scope like this.
